# What is Euler Characteristic of $RP^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

$RP^2$ has two diagrams:

Figure 1:
Square where opposite edges are identified antipodally

Figure 2:
Circle with antipodal identification.

However, the first figure has
$V = 1, E = 2, F = 1$, and the second figure has: $V = 1, E = 1, F = 1$.
Which one is right?

Comment: Hint: For the square representation of $\Bbb RP^2$, how many vertices are there? only one? Notice how the edges are identified, there are more than one vertex. Once you correct that issue, you'll find that the two diagrams agree on the euler characteristic.

Comment: @Kevin.S Oh I see. There are two vertices in the second figure. Thank you.